# how to delete the table on clicking link without calling in session?

Tags: php, html, session

how to delete the table record when user click sign out ,sign out its just a link its is not called in session ,is there any way for doing this .where ever the user click the sign out link the record of that particular table delete. i don't this in session but i don't know how can i achieved this without session.
coding for calling in session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("ems" , $con);
$r="delete from ga2";
$result=mysql_query($r) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

how to delete the above table without session when user click sign out link.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what your question is? I don't understand. Anyway, if you are creating a table *for each user that is logged in* you may want to change your approach, that doesn't sound ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete from ga2` will delete all records from `ga2` `table`. To prevent this, on login store user `id` in `session` and `ga2` `table`. Then on logout you can do something like this to delete the record:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $user_id = (int) $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("ems" , $con) or die('Could select database: ' . mysql_error());
    $r = "delete from ga2 WHERE user_id = $user_id";
    mysql_query($r) or die (mysql_error());
    session_destroy();
}

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A separate table for each user is a very bad coding approach. Instead, have just one table, and one row in the table per user. And as #manoj-yadav suggested, delete the row while logout. A note to you and #manoj-yadav: please use mysqli instead of mysql api as mysql api is deprecated. php.net says "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future."